# FireFox document.exeCommand('copy') not working

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have the following code :

```
   var doc = window.document;
   var copyFrom = doc.createElement("textarea");
   copyFrom.textContent = str;
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   body.appendChild(copyFrom);
   copyFrom.select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
   body.removeChild(copyFrom);
```

This seems to work fine on Chrome as I am able to paste the contents on my 'str' variable. However this doesn't seem to work on FireFox/Safari.

Comment: Have you try to update your firefox?

Answer (score 0):

[Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7475069?start=0&tstart=0) does not give clipboard access without user generated event. So only user initiated actions ( e.g Ctrl + C/ Cmd + C) can work to copy items.

About Firefox, can you give some details regarding the version. There has been a change post 44.0 where copy to clipboard has been enabled.

Comment: Hi I'm using FireFox 49.